# Share iCloud Family Calendar with Outlook

Tags: calendar

My wife and I use the iCloud shared Family calendar for scheduling family events. I would like to be able to view this calendar from my work Outlook account. Is there some way to share the calendar with non-Apple calendar applications?

Comment: Can you provide a link? There doesn't appear to be a current Apple product by that name?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, I am assuming by "Outlook" you mean the Outlook email client application and not an @outlook.com email account. In other words, your work computer uses the Exchange/Outlook system for emails, calendar, and so on.

If so - and assuming your IT department would permit this - you could try the iCloud Control Panel on your work computer. This add-in for Outlook will sync the Outlook email app with your iCloud email, calendar, and contacts - including your Family Calendar.

Instructions can be found on Apple's website. Good luck!